# Configuration for pom.xml to buil an rpm

Tags: pom.xml

I have a below folder structure :

/a/b/c/test.sh
location of POM : /a/pom.xml

I need a pom.xml file for generating rpm for this.

Condition: When deploying this rpm the script test.sh should automatically run.

Please help.

Answer (score -1):

[MojoHaus](http://www.mojohaus.org/) maintains an [RPM plugin for Maven](http://www.mojohaus.org/rpm-maven-plugin/index.html) that will help build an RPM as part of your Maven build. You can also take a look at this [example pom.xml file](https://github.com/rombert/Maven-Recipe--RPM-Package/blob/master/pom.xml) to help you get started.